# NetShareGetInfo doesn't return permissions

Tags: c, winapi

I've shared a directory with the (*OSSMBSHARE_PERMISSIONS_ATRIB | OSSMBSHARE_PERMISSIONS_EXEC | OSSMBSHARE_PERMISSIONS_READ*) permissions, but when I call **NetShareGetInfo** on the share, the permissions are 0 (while all of the other fields are correct).

Code:

```
    /* Initialize the share info structure */
    tShareInfo.shi2_netname = pwstrNetName;
    tShareInfo.shi2_type = STYPE_DISKTREE;
    tShareInfo.shi2_remark = L"";
    tShareInfo.shi2_permissions = OSSMBSHARE_PERMISSIONS_ATRIB | OSSMBSHARE_PERMISSIONS_EXEC | OSSMBSHARE_PERMISSIONS_READ;
    tShareInfo.shi2_max_uses = (DWORD)-1;
    tShareInfo.shi2_current_uses = 0;
    tShareInfo.shi2_path = pwstrPath;
    tShareInfo.shi2_passwd = NULL; 

    /* Add the share */
    eResult = NetShareAdd(NULL, 2, (LPBYTE)&tShareInfo, &dwError);
    if (NERR_Success != eResult)
    {
        printf("Failed sharing\n");
        goto lbl_cleanup;
    }
    eResult = NetShareGetInfo(NULL, pwstrNetName, 2, (LPBYTE *)&ptShareInfo);
    if (NERR_Success == eResult)
    {
        printf("Path: %s\n", ptShareInfo->shi2_path);
        printf("Permissions: %d\n", ptShareInfo->shi2_permissions);
    }
```

What can be the problem here?

Comment: Did you try to log-off and then log-in again? it is probably one of the problems with net shares

Comment: but about [`shi2_permissions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525408(v=vs.85).aspx) - *A server running user-level security ignores this member.* and *Calls to the NetShareSetInfo function ignore this member* - *Note that Windows does not support share-level security*

Comment: RbMm is correct, the field you're using is only useful with legacy or third-party servers.  I *think* you want `shixxx_security_descriptor`, which is available at levels 502, 503, and 1501.  Although that might turn out to be the ACL of the share directory rather than the ACL of the share, I'm not certain.

Comment: @RbMm That's weird.. If windows doesn't support share-level security then what does?! Isn't SMB a Microsoft protocol? anyway I guess you can post this as the answer

Comment: Wait, but there is some kind of share-level permissions.. How can I use it? (The shi2_permissions and shi502_permissions seems to be the same)